# Problems passing a Python String to SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, regex, pyodbc

I got some issues passing my SQL query made in Python to MS SQL.

Were talking about retrieving some code via `pyodbc`, editing it with regex, and passing it back into a new table of the Database.
I also tried some `print()`-Commands to assure the Code is running in Python and being edited the right way, but I am not able to write those contents back to  SQL after editing the strings.

Im trying to pass the string via:

```
try:   
    values = ""
    for row in cursor.execute("select row1, row2 from db_table"):
        cleanheader = cleanhtml(str(row.row1))
        cleanbody = cleanhtml(str(row.row2))
        values = values + "('" + cleanheader + "','" + cleanbody + "'),"
    values[0:len(values)-1]
    values = values + ";"
    sql = "INSERT INTO db_new_table VALUES ('"+str(values)+"')"
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

whereas `cleanhtml()` refers to my regex-function:

```
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return cleantext
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to pass those lines correctly to SQL?

Comment: Never, EVER, use string concatenation to add data to an SQL query.  It's a Massive security hole *(SQL Injection Attack)*.  Always us parametrised queries... https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a prepared statement rather than concatenation, which is vulnerable to SQL Injection, by creating an auxiliary list(`row`) to append the each processed member of the tuples coming from the cursor, and prefer using `executemany` rather than `execute` as being more performant such as

```
row=[]
for i in cursor.execute("SELECT col1, col2 FROM db_table"):
        cleanheader = cleanhtml(str(i[0]))
        cleanbody = cleanhtml(str(i[1]))
        row.append((cleanheader,cleanbody),)        

for i in row:
        cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO db_new_table VALUES(?,?)',([i]))

con.commit()
con.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are quoting twice the data in VALUES block with single-quotes. It seems that you are also messing up the parenthesis there. Print out your query before executing it.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO db_new_table VALUES ('"+str(values)+"')"
```

values here is already quoted and in parenthesis.